# Microsoft SCCM with Linux Clients

Tags: linux, sccm

I am using Microsoft SCCM 1606 to deploy software to a Ubuntu 18.04 endpoint. My issue is that I am completely new to SCCM. The SCCM Console does not show this Linux endpoint (it does show 3 Windows end points). I've been googling and comping up empty.

How do I locate my Linux endpoint with SCCM?

I need to copy software to this endpoint, so any help there would be great too but finding the endpoint is where I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX/Linux management was deprecated for ConfigMgr 1902 and greater. Ubuntu 18.04 is not in supported operating systems list. However, I've done some changes to manage them too:

1. Execute a query in a CM database.

```
INSERT INTO SupportedPlatforms
    (Id, OSPlatform, OSName, OSMinVersion, OSMaxVersion, DisplayText, StringId, Condition, ClientSupported, Metric, BitMask, HybridSupported)
    VALUES
    (4148, 'x86', 'Debian', '9.00.0000.0', '9.99.9999.9999', 'x86 Debian 9', 4148, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''9%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Debian GNU/Linux 9%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=0]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0),
    (4149, 'x64', 'Debian', '9.00.0000.0', '9.99.9999.9999', 'x64 Debian 9', 4149, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''9%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Debian GNU/Linux 9%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=9]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0),
    (4150, 'x86', 'Ubuntu', '18.04.0000.0', '18.04.9999.9999', 'x86 Ubuntu 18.04', 4150, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''18.%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Ubuntu 18%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=0]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0),
    (4151, 'x64', 'Ubuntu', '18.04.0000.0', '18.04.9999.9999', 'x64 Ubuntu 18.04', 4151, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''18.%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Ubuntu 18%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=9]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0),
    (4152, 'x86', 'Debian', '10.00.0000.0', '10.99.9999.9999', 'x86 Debian 10', 4152, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''10%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Debian GNU/Linux 10%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=0]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0),
    (4153, 'x64', 'Debian', '10.00.0000.0', '10.99.9999.9999', 'x64 Debian 10', 4153, '<Operator OperatorType="AND"><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE Version like ''10%'' AND OSType=36 AND Caption like ''%Debian GNU/Linux 10%'']]></Expression><Expression ExpressionType="continuous" ExpressionLanguage="WQL"><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor WHERE Architecture=9]]></Expression></Operator>', 1, 200, 0, 0)
```

2. Install latest [omiagent](https://github.com/microsoft/omi/releases) on Ubuntu computers.
3. Download and unpack [Clients for Additional Operating Systems](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=47719).
4. Change a line `OPENSSL_SYSTEM_VERSION_100=` in the install script on this `` OPENSSL_SYSTEM_VERSION_100=`echo $OPENSSL_SYSTEM_VERSION_FULL | grep -Eq '^1.(0|1).'; echo $?` ``.
5. Install agent as it described here - [How to deploy clients to UNIX and Linux servers in Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/deploy/deploy-clients-to-unix-and-linux-servers).

**You should understand that is not supported scenario.**